# Undefined TypeError when accessing object property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an Array, which outputs in console:

```
HOUSES (11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

I need only first object value. So, when i console first element like this:

```
console.log("SINGLE HOUSE", houses[0])
```

I get the first element, as you can see:

```
SINGLE HOUSE 
{id: 1, count: 0, name: "House1", image: "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-business-desktop-icons/256/Home.png"}
count: 0
id: 1
image: "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-business-desktop-icons/256/Home.png"
name: "House1"
__proto__: Object
```

But when I try to access first object's name property, like this:

```
console.log("SINGLE HOUSE", houses[0].name)
```

I am getting an error, it says that 'name' is undefined:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

This is how my Component looks:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Image from "../../components/Image/Image";
import Title from "../../components/Title/Title";
import Counter from "../../components/Counter/Counter";
import Button from "../../components/Button/Button";

import {Single} from "./HouseSingle.styled";
import { getSingleHouseAPI } from "../../services/api";
import { getHousesAPI } from "../../services/api";
import { getHouses, getSingleHouse } from '../../state/house/actions';


const HouseSingle = (props) => {

     const { house, houses } = props

     const { image, name, id, count} = house;
     //  const { image, name, id, count} = houses[0];


    const handleIncrement = (data) => {
     console.log('increment')
    }

    const handleDecrement = (data) => {
     console.log('decrement')
     }


      console.log("SINGLE HOUSE", houses[0])
    return ( 

        <Single>
        <div className="house">
         <Image src={image} />  
          <Title title={name} />

          <Counter count={count} />

          <Button type="Increment" onClick={handleIncrement}/>
          <Button type="Decrement" onClick={handleDecrement} />

        </div>
        </Single>
     );
}


const matStateToProps = state => {
     const { house: { singleHouse: { data: house } }} = state;
     const { house: { allHouses: {data: houses}}} = state;
     return {
          house,
          houses
     }
}
export default connect(matStateToProps)(HouseSingle);
```

Comment: No, that error is saying that houses[0] is undefined. Whenever you're console logging this, somehow it seems like the array hasn't been filled yet.

Comment: If it's reactjs, can you provide the code a bit more to understand the context?

Comment: I've added the component

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that the property you are trying to access might not exist yet if you console.log.

Try this .

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    var houseName = houses[0].name ;  
}, 
100);
```